# Wordpress excerpt by second paragraph

Tags: wordpress, paragraph

How to limit the excerpt length by paragraph, not word/char count? For example, excerpt shows only first two paragraphs, no matter how long the paragraphs are.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that keeps HTML tags in tact, adds a "Read More" link at the end of the excerpt and trims the excerpt after the first paragraph.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse0001_custom_wp_trim_excerpt' ) ) : 

function wpse0001_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($wpse0001_excerpt) {
global $post;
$raw_excerpt = $wpse0001_excerpt;
if ( '' == $wpse0001_excerpt ) {

$wpse0001_excerpt = get_the_content('');
$wpse0001_excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $wpse0001_excerpt );
$wpse0001_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $wpse0001_excerpt);
// Here we choose how many paragraphs do we want to cutthe excerpt at, This part thanks to Clément Malet
$wpse0001_excerpt = "<p>$wpse0001_excerpt</p>";
    $wanted_number_of_paragraph = 2;
    $tmp = explode ('</p>', $wpse0001_excerpt);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $wanted_number_of_paragraph; ++$i) {
       if (isset($tmp[$i]) && $tmp[$i] != '') {
           $tmp_to_add[$i] = $tmp[$i];
       }
    }
$wpse0001_excerpt = implode('</p>', $tmp_to_add) . '</p>';

$wpse0001_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $wpse0001_excerpt);

$excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__( 'Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ), get_the_title()) . '</a>'; 
$excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end); 

//$pos = strrpos($wpse0001_excerpt, '</');
//if ($pos !== false)
// Inside last HTML tag
//$wpse0001_excerpt = substr_replace($wpse0001_excerpt, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0);
//else
// After the content
$wpse0001_excerpt .= $excerpt_end;

return $wpse0001_excerpt;

}
return apply_filters('wpse0001_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $wpse0001_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
}

endif; 

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse0001_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to the help from @ClementMalet, I was able to tweak my function to make you choose the amount of paragraphs where you want to cut the excerpt. Please check his great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24824234/1908141)

Comment: Thanks, Pieter. How to make it trim after second paragraph?