# Custom Wordpress Excerpt by two paragraphs

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

I found the answers to limiting the excerpts to only 2 paragraphs or more. However, the code I found only apply to the actual excerpt, not to custom excerpt that I made. I made two excerpts, one for certain posts on front page and another for the posts page. I wanted to add that code to the custom excerpt that I made for the posts page. How do I do that.

Here's my code that I created:

```
// Create the Custom Excerpts callback
function wpden_excerpt($length_callback = '', $more_callback = '')
{
    global $post;
    if (function_exists($length_callback)) {
        add_filter('excerpt_length', $length_callback);
    }
    if (function_exists($more_callback)) {
        add_filter('excerpt_more', $more_callback);
    }
    $output = get_the_excerpt();
    $output = apply_filters('wptexturize', $output);
    $output = apply_filters('convert_chars', $output);
    $output = '<p>' . $output . '</p>';
    echo $output;
}
// Custom Length 
function wpden_mag_len($length) {
    return 200;
}
function wpden_more_view($more){
global $post;
return '... <a class="view-article" href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . __('', 'wpden') . '</a>';
}
```

And I called it in my template_post.php:

```
<?php wpden_excerpt('wpden_mag_len','wpden_more_view'); ?>
```

The code in question that I wanted to use for my custom wpden_excerpt is either this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'my_custom_excerpt', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_excerpt($text, $raw_excerpt) {
    if( ! $raw_excerpt ) {
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        $text = substr( $content, 0, strpos( $content, '</p>' ) + 4 );
    }
    return $text;
}
```

from [this site](http://www.codecheese.com/2013/11/get-the-first-paragraph-as-an-excerpt-for-wordpress/) or from the other [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805636/wordpress-excerpt-by-second-paragraph)

```
$wpse0001_excerpt = get_the_content('');
$wpse0001_excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $wpse0001_excerpt );
$wpse0001_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $wpse0001_excerpt);
// Here we choose how many paragraphs do we want to cutthe excerpt at, This part thanks to Clément Malet
$wpse0001_excerpt = "<p>$wpse0001_excerpt</p>";
    $wanted_number_of_paragraph = 2;
    $tmp = explode ('</p>', $wpse0001_excerpt);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $wanted_number_of_paragraph; ++$i) {
       if (isset($tmp[$i]) && $tmp[$i] != '') {
           $tmp_to_add[$i] = $tmp[$i];
       }
    }
$wpse0001_excerpt = implode('</p>', $tmp_to_add) . '</p>';

$wpse0001_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $wpse0001_excerpt);

$excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__( 'Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ), get_the_title()) . '</a>'; 
$excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end); 

//$pos = strrpos($wpse0001_excerpt, '</');
//if ($pos !== false)
// Inside last HTML tag
//$wpse0001_excerpt = substr_replace($wpse0001_excerpt, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0);
//else
// After the content
$wpse0001_excerpt .= $excerpt_end;

return $wpse0001_excerpt;

}
return apply_filters('wpse0001_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $wpse0001_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
}

endif; 

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse0001_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

The thing is that those codes in question apply to the the_excerpt and override the custom excerpt that I made. I tried to format the code like this:

```
function wpden_excerpt($text = '')
{
   global $post;
        if ( '' == $text ) {
                $text = get_the_content('');
                $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
                $text = str_replace('\]\]\>', ']]&gt;', $text);
                $text = preg_replace('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si', '', $text);
                $text = strip_tags($text, '<p>');
                $excerpt_length = 80;
                $words = explode(' ', $text, $excerpt_length + 1);
                if (count($words)> $excerpt_length) {
                        array_pop($words);
                        array_push($words, '[...]');
                        $text = implode(' ', $words);
                }
        }
        return $text;
}
```

and called it in the template as

```
<?php wpden_excerpt('text'); ?>
```

But it's not working. What was wrong and how do I fix it?

**UPDATE**

I still need help!!! I tried many different combo of custom excerpt and limiting the excerpt to one paragraph and I wasn't able to do so... Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my brother's help, I was able to edit the code to show two paragraphs for a custom excerpt:

```
// Create the Custom Excerpts callback
function wpden_excerpt()
{
    global $post;

   $output = get_the_content();

$wanted_number_of_paragraph = 2;

$tmp = explode ('</p>', $output);
for ($i = 0; $i < $wanted_number_of_paragraph; ++$i) {
   if (isset($tmp[$i]) && $tmp[$i] != '') {
       $tmp_to_add[$i] = $tmp[$i];
   }
}
$output = implode('</p>', $tmp_to_add) . '</p>';

    echo $output;

}
```

and call it in my template file as

```
<?php wpden_excerpt(); ?>
```